# Regular Expression to extract label-value pairs in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a file containing several lines similar to:

```
Name: Peter
Address: St. Serrano número 12, España
Country: Spain
```

And I need to extract the address using a regular expression, taking into account that it can contain dots, special characters (ñ, ç), áéíóú...

The current code works, but it looks quite ugly:.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)Address: ([a-zA-Z0-9ñÑçÇáéíóú., ]+)(.+?)$",
                            Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
if (m.matches()) { ... }
```

**Edit: The Address field could also be divided into multiple lines**

```
Name: Peter
Address: St. Serrano número 12,   
Madrid
España
Country: Spain
```

Edit: I can't use a Properties object or a YAML parser, as the file contains other kind of information, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know Java's regex objects that well, but something like this pattern will do it:

```
^Address:\s*((?:(?!^\w+:).)+)$
```

assuming multiline and dotall modes are on.

This will match any line starting with Address, followed by anything until a newline character and a single word followed by a colon.

If you know the next field has to be "Country", you can simplify this a little bit:

```
^Address:\s*((?:(?!^Country:).)+)$
```

The trick is in the lookahead assertion in the repeating group. '(?!Country:).' will match everything except the start of the string 'Country:', so we just stick it in noncapturing parentheses (?:...) and quantify it with +, then group all of that in normal capturing parentheses.

Comment: Anyone reading this. For the multi-line case the flag DOTALL needs to be passed and ^ and $ need to be removed from the case.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [`Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) class instead of regex. It provides you ways to manage plain text or XML files to represent key-value pairs.

So you can read in your example file and then get the values like so after loading to a `Properties` object:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(/* InputStream of your file */);

Assert.assertEquals("Peter", properties.getProperty("Name"));
Assert.assertEquals("St. Serrano número 12, España", properties.getProperty("Address"));
Assert.assertEquals("Spain", properties.getProperty("Country"));
```

Comment: Why use Apache Commons Assert isntead of Java assert?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming "content" is a string containing the file's contents, your main problem is that you're using `matches()` where you should be using `find()`.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^Address:\\s*(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
if ( m.find() )
{
  ...
}
```

There seems to be some confusion in other answers about MULTLINE and DOTALL modes.  MULTILINE is what lets the `^` and `$` anchors match the beginning and end, respectively, of a logical line.  DOTALL lets the dot (period, full stop, whatever) match line separator characters like `\n` (linefeed) and `\r` (carriage return).  This regex **must** use MULTILINE mode and **must not** use DOTALL mode.

Comment: Thanks. What if address is a multiline field ? Is it possible to capture it with no need to depend on the next field name ?

Comment: Both of Nick's regexes will match if the Address field is at the end of the input.  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to be a stick in the mud, but do you have to use a regex? Why not spare your future self (or others) the headache and do:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null)
{
    line = line.trim();
    if(line.startsWith("Address: "))
    {
        return line.substr("Address: ".length()).trim();
    }
    line = reader.readLine();
}
return null;
```

Of course this can be parameterized a bit as well and put into a method.

Otherwise, I'd second the Properties or JYaml suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Java person, but wouldn't a `"Address: (.*)$"` work?

Edit: Without the Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL option it should match only on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Can it contain a newline? If it cannot contain a newline, you don't need to use the multiline modifier, and can do instead

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^Address: (.*)$");
```

If it can, an alternative I can think of is

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Address: (.*)\nCountry", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Without the DOTALL, the dot won't match a newline, so you can explicitly specify it in the regexp, allowing you to do what you asked about.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check out [YAML](http://yaml.org).

You could try [JYaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/).

Best of all it has implementations in many languages.

*ps I have tried the sample text in [YAML::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML::XS), and it works perfectly.*